# Good ruby irc client library

Tags: ruby, irc, bots

I'd like to write an irc bot. (please reply with a good irc client library and not a bot framework).

__

why the downvote? I simply like to know which libary is fairly decent and well maintained as there are quite a few ruby irc libraries.

Comment: Download them and check the changelog or git/svn/mercurial whatever logs and see when the last update was.

Answer (score 1):

My friend used RBot.

I wrote my own. It's not hard to make.

You can find minimal bots' samples even on SO: [My Ruby IRC bot doesn't connect to the IRC server. What am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356040/ruby-irc-bot-dont-works)